# Find how much of a string is needed before it becomes unique among a set of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

This is difficult to explain, but I'll do my best...

I have an array of strings. Let's use an example here:

```
var myArray = [
    "hello there my friend robert"
    "hello there friend kimberly"
    "hello friend claire"
    "hi there friend chris"
]
```

I'm trying to write a function that will determine how many words of each string in the array are needed before it becomes unique. For example, using the above array as input, the function should return the following:

```
[
    "hello there my",
    "hello there friend",
    "hello friend",
    "hi"
]
```

The strings in the returned array represent the words needed for each string before the string becomes unique.

For instance, the function returns "hello there my" for "hello there my friend robert." This is because "hello there" on its own is ambiguous. It could refer to either "hello there my friend robert" or "hello there friend kimberly." However, "hello there my" could only refer to "hello there my friend robert."

I'm totally at a loss for how to accomplish this. Does anyone else know of a solution?

(For simplicity, assume the input strings have no punctuation and are entirely lowercase.)

Comment: it should be ```'hi'``` because the first word is not the same as others

Comment: @YasharthDubey is correct. I'm trying to find how many words are needed starting from the beginning of the string. Since "chris" is at the end of the string, it wouldn't be used.

Comment: have you tried my solution brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have some idea regarding it. What you can do is store the list like.

```
{
   'first' : ['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'hi'],
   'second' : ['there','friend','there'],
   'third' : ['my', 'friend', 'claire'],
   'fourth' : ['robert', 'kimberly', 'chris']
}
```

now just check if the count of the first is more than one on this map then you have to go ahead and if the count is one, you have to stop there.

Comment: This seems like a smart way to do it! I just need to convert the array to this format first. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

```
var myArray = [
    "hello there my friend robert",
    "bb gnhgn",
    "hello there friend kimberly",
    "hello friend claire",
    "hi there friend chris"
];
function prepareArray(arr){
    let res = [];
  
    arr.forEach((element) => {
        console.log(element.split(" "));
        res.push(element.split(" "));
    });
   
    return res;
}
function calcWordsWeights(splitedArr){
   let res = [];
   let searchMask = new Array(splitedArr.length).fill(1);
  
   for(let i=0;i<getMaxLength(splitedArr);i++){
        splitedArr.forEach((elem,index)=>{
           
            if(searchMask[index]==true){
            if(res.length <= i){
                res[i]=[];
               
            }
            let isAdded=false;
            if(res[i].length<=0){
                res[i].push({word:elem[i],weight:0});
               
            }else{
                res[i].forEach(e=>{
                    if(e.word == elem[i]){
                        e.weight=e.weight+1;  
                        isAdded=true;  
                    }
                    
                });
                if(!isAdded){
                    res[i].push({word:elem[i],weight:0});
                }
            }
        
           
        }
        });
        if(res[i]==undefined){
            break;
        }else{
            res[i].forEach(el=>{
                if(el.weight==0){
                    for(let index in splitedArr){
                        if(splitedArr[index][i]==el.word){
                            searchMask[index]=0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
     
     
        
   }
   console.log(res);
   return res;
}
function regenerateUniqueSentences(resArr){
    console.log(resArr);
    let numOfUniqueSentences=0; 
     resArr[0].forEach(el=>{
        numOfUniqueSentences += el.weight+1;
    });

    const finalRes =[];
   
  
    resArr.forEach((el,index)=>{
        let counter =0;
        
        el.forEach(e=>{
            for(let x=0;x<= e.weight;x++){
                if(index==0){
                    finalRes.push({txt:e.word,isDone:(e.weight==0?true:false)});
                }else{
                    if(!finalRes[counter].isDone){
                        finalRes[counter].txt += " "+ e.word;
                    }
                } 
                counter++;  
            }
        });
    });
   return finalRes;
}
function checkForExistingWord(resArr,word){
    let isExist =false;
    resArr.forEach(elem=>{
        if(elem.word == undefined  ){
            return false;
        }else if(elem.word == word){
            return true;
        }
    })
}
function getMaxLength(arr){
    let max=0;
    arr.forEach((element)=>{
        if(max < element.length)
            max= element.length;
    });
    return max
}
function stopSearchInArray(arr,word,weight){

}
(function(){
    const splitedArr = prepareArray(myArray);
    const weigthedArr =calcWordsWeights(splitedArr);
    console.log(regenerateUniqueSentences(weigthedArr));
})();
```